# I would like that one of my NavigationStack act like a NavigationLink

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui

I have a TabView with 5 NavigationStack's and 5 icons that works perfectly. When you tap on it it's a change of view, not a naviagationlink that you can go back from. I would like to make one of these 5 a NavigationLink in the same tabbar. When press on the "Question Mark" go and then be able to go back.

This is because when I press the QuestionMark I want to Hide the tab bar.

My current Tabview is:

```
import SwiftUI

struct TabbarView: View {
    @Binding var showSignInView: Bool
    @StateObject private var profileModel = ProfileModel()

    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            NavigationStack {
                FeedView(showSignInView: $showSignInView)
            }
            .tabItem {
                Image(systemName: "house")
            }
            
            NavigationStack {
                SearchView(showSignInView: $showSignInView)
            }
            .tabItem {
                Image(systemName: "magnifyingglass")
            }
            
            NavigationStack {
                NavigationLink(destination: NewQuestionStart(showSignInView: $showSignInView)) {
                    Text("Ir a NewQuestionStart")
                }
            }
            .tabItem {
                Image(systemName: "questionmark")
            }
            
            NavigationStack {
                InboxView(showSignInView: $showSignInView)
            }
            .tabItem {
                Image(systemName: "tray.full")
            }
        
            NavigationStack {
                if let user = profileModel.user {
                    ProfileView(showSignInView: $showSignInView, user: user)
                }
            }
            .tabItem {
                Image(systemName: "person")
            }
            .onAppear {
                profileModel.loadUserDetails()
            }
        }
        .background(Color("TabbarBackground"))
    }
}
```

The fact is that when I don't really get how to make a questionmark icon that when presses go like a navigationlink on this tabview that I am using on the main app and all views of it.

What this makes:

```
NavigationStack {
    NavigationLink(destination: NewQuestionStart(showSignInView: $showSignInView)) {
        Text("Ir a NewQuestionStart")
    }
}
.tabItem {
    Image(systemName: "questionmark")
}
```

Is that you press there and then have to press a link to go and I want it to act as a tabitem that you just tap on it and I am thinking there is no way.